# How to ignore HTTP Error and finish request

Tags: python, http, urllib

I do a request to 'someurl' and have redirected. The redirect link does't exist, but in the link I have access_token and others important data. I like to get this redirect url with out program crash.

```
a = opener.open('https://connect.ok.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=1247511808&scope=VALUABLE_ACCESS&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://smasu.ru')
```

So, redirect to site smasu.ru, but this site does't exist. The link will have type as:

https://smasu.ru/#access_token=8.7fd19d96afcfc687b92bd50e2df6011837b94753e09f315818c0328e9&session_secret_key=363b5dd2ab1a1a44c25e423e892732ce&permissions_granted=VALUABLE_ACCESS&expires_in=1800

Where you can see acces_token, session_secret_key, that I want take for my program. How to do a request with ignore HTTP Error and get the redirect url?

Traceback:

[image]

Comment: You might try calling the [`geturl()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#info-and-geturl) method of the `HTTPError` instance that's raised (after you catch it).  Also, consider using as a "fake" redirect URI something like `localhost` -- `getaddrinfo` shouldn't fail on that, and you should be able to get an `HTTPError` instead of the `URLError` you're getting.

Comment: This means it is an issue with the DNS/resolver on the network.